# background image is too zoomed

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

my background image on the div looks too zoomed and is not clear it loses it clarity 
this the html and styling that i've tried

```
<div class="grid-x intro">
        <div class="cell large-12 medium-12 small-12 one">
        </div>
      </div>
        <!-- end of intro -->
styling

.intro{

background-image: url("../images/house4.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
/* height: auto; */
padding-top: 66.64%;
}
```

Comment: try adding object-fit: cover

Comment: tried it no difference

Comment: Add your code to codepen and share codepen url for better debugging.  Also add image to codepen

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mariwa/xLm4q82s/

Comment: @FerinPatel One does not need codepen to do that and can easily use snippets within the question. Using codepen, instead of producing a [mcve] here, within the question, may get this question closed.

Answer (score 1):

> It's okkey in here ... use `"background-size: 100% auto;"`
>   This is because your image is more wider then height & u used `background-size: cover;` . To cover all background, that's why it's zoomed and cropped rest width
>   **Your code is okkey, just use resized image like 500px*333.2px (or around this ratio) to show all image inside 66.64% padding**
>
> ```css
> .intro{
>
> background-image: url("https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/geometric-models-gradient-background_23-2148326516.jpg");
> background-size: 100% auto;
> background-repeat: no-repeat;
> width: 100%;
> /* height: auto; */
> padding-top: 66.64%;
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <div class="grid-x intro">
>         <div class="cell large-12 medium-12 small-12 one">
>         </div>
>       </div>
>         <!-- end of intro -->
> ```

Answer (score 0):

May be the quality of the image is not great. Or if you don't need full covered background, you can shrink the background image by doing

```
background-size: 50%;
```